# how to upload a file to url

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to upload a file from browser and copy it to a URL folder

using c sharp.

( i have all the Permissions to this folder)

i have no problam upload the file to my hard drive

like this:

```
HttpPostedFileBase myfile;

var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/txt"), fileName);

myfile.SaveAs(path);
```

i have try to upload it to URL like this but i am getting an exception

```
HttpPostedFileBase myfile;

var path =VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("http://localhost:8080/game/images/"+fileName);

myfile.SaveAs(path);
```

the Exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: The relative virtual path 'http:/localhost:8080/game/images/ a baby bottle. Jpg' is not allowed here.
    In - System.Web.VirtualPath.Create (String virtualPath, VirtualPathOptions
```

Comment: Can you please post text from the exception so the rest of us can learn from it as well?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot upload the file to a remote location. If you want this to work you will have to modify the remote server so that it accepts file uploads, the same way your server accepts file uploads and then send an HTTP request to it using a `WebClient`. You cannot use the `SaveAs` method as it expects a local path.

You could have the following controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase myFile)
{
    if (myFile != null && myFile.ContentLength > 0) 
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(myFile.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);
        myFile.SaveAs(path);
    }    

    ...
}
```

and a corresponding form with a file input:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="myFile" />
    <button type="submit">Click this to upload the file</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Server.MapPath("Path")`

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/images/") + fileName);
myfile.SaveAs(path);
```